# Unity Adding Box Colliders Changes Mesh dynamics

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes

I have a bi-pedal mesh in unity.
I'm adding box colliders to each bone in a mesh so the user is able to individually select each bone.
However, when I add the colliders it changes the dynamics of the mesh, when I rotate the the joint the colliders add weight to the mesh making the parts bend in in proper places

Is there a way I can add the box colliders, without having it effect the dynamics of the mesh?

Comment: Why not give them `MeshCollider`s instead? That could save you a lot of pain.

Comment: If there is a Rigidbody component on each body part you can decrease mass value

Comment: @JohnHamilton if I add a mesh collider wont that be applied to the whole mesh instead of the individual sections that i need?

Comment: ill try that out